# highcharts parseMarkup report a warning. This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”

Tags: highcharts, domparser, quirks-mode

`This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”.`
The warning is from method `parseMarkup`.

How to suppress the warning?
It seems an internal method and I don't know how to trigger this.
[source code](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/09c8f20533ea21a130a5dde396d9d8018a3c960c/ts/Core/Renderer/HTML/AST.ts#L575)

Comment: Your HTML document should starts with a valid DOCTYPE declaration, so can you ensure that it starts from the `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Comment: Sure, I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the begin of html file.

Comment: Could you please reproduce this issue in the online demo? You can start here:https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pqmjab1y/